# Run shell in subprocess.run(cmd_line) using one line cmd string

Tags: python

`os.system()` invokes a command, the argument can be a single string, e.g,

`os.system("cmd -input xx --output yy")`.

But subprocess, I have to pass a list for args, e.g.,

`subprocess.run(["cmd", "-input", "xx", "--output", "yy"])`.

For complex arguments, passing a list is trivial. So how to pass a single string to run a command and can also try exceptions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

cmd_string = 'cmd -input xx --output yy'

subprocess.run(cmd_string.split())

Answer (score 0):

you can simply split the command string and pass it to `subprocess` like bellow:
`subprocess.run("your cmd command".split())`